# Adding value to input with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to add a value into an input field with jQuery and that means I need to add (append) it to the present value.

```
var id = move.attr("data-id");

$("input[name=jmeno]").attr("value",id);
```

It is a piece of dropable loop and i need to add value after every dropable effect.

I hope to add all information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you want, but I am going to take a guess that you want to set the value of a textbox.

If you want to set the value of a textbox using jQuery, you'll be using the `.val()`

So in your case,

```
var id = move.attr("data-id");


$("input[name=jmeno]").val(id);
```

I'm not really able to understand what you want, if you want to add the value inside the textbox to the value that you have in `id` you'll do this...

```
    var id = parseInt(move.attr("data-id"), 10);

    // Getting the value, use parse int if it's an integer.
    var intValue = parseInt($("input[name=jmeno]").val(), 10);

    // Adding and Setting the value...
    $("input[name=jmeno]").val(intValue + id);
```

Comment: You should really be using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: **NOTE**: _parseInt_ without _radix_ is not compatible in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are asking for,

```
    $("input[name=jmeno]").attr("value", pareseInt( move.data("id")) + parseInt( $("input[name=jmeno]").attr("value") ) );
```

Or may be if you want to actually input into the value attribute you just need to change:

```
   $("input[name=jmeno]").val( parseInt( move.data("id")) + parseInt( $("input[name=jmeno]").val() ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure what you mean

```
var id = move.attr("data-id");


$("input[name='jmeno']").attr("value", $("input[name='jmeno']").attr("value") + id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question, but is it something like

```
var $input = $("input[name=jmeno]");
$input.attr("value", $input.attr('value') + id);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-functionindex--value) should be used to access or modify a input's value, not `.attr()`

```
var id = move.attr("data-id");
$("input[name=jmeno]").val(function(i,val) { // <-- val is the current value
     return val + id;
});
```

This would append it to the present value, or to add to a numerical value:

```
var id = move.attr("data-id");
$("input[name=jmeno]").val(function(i,val) { // <-- val is the current value
     return (val*1) + (id*1); // <-- *1 forces them to numbers
});
```